# ASP.NET tableadapter insert not returning the correct identity value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In my Visual Studio 2008 ASP.NET web page codebehind, I am calling an add routine in an SQL tableadapter, as follows.

```
NewLabID = LabItem.AddLaborItem(ThisWONum, TechID, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, "Working", "");
```

The record is being added correctly, but 'NewLabID' returns 1 every time, not the actual new LabID (LabID is defined as int/identity). The autogenerated code insert command is

```
INSERT INTO [LaborDetail] ([WONum], [TechID], [StartDate], [StopDate], [OtherType], [OtherDesc])
VALUES (@WONum, @TechID, @StartDate, @StopDate, @OtherType, @OtherDesc);
SELECT LabID FROM LaborDetail WHERE (LabID = SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

and the autogenerated code which calls this is:

```
returnValue = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Stepping through this with the debugger, returnValue is always 1.  Shouldn't the above command return the new identity field value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected. You will want to use ExecuteScalar() instead.

Comment: Thanks - but how do I get asp.net to autogenerate ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteNonQuery?  The autogenerated command is clearly designed to return the new ID.

Comment: OK, I got it - I had to change the ExecuteMode property of the query in the table adapter.