# ADO.NET autoincrement primary keys

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, ado.net

I'm trying to use SQLite with ADO.NET TableAdapters and xsd schema.

What is the best practice of generating autoincrement values? SQLite manual says that key is generated automatically if NULL is sent for PRIMARY KEY field. But schema editor doesn't allow NULL.

With DataReader it's probably easier, but I would like to use functionality of TableAdapters.

*-- UPDATE --*

This was somewhere helpful:
[msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/5b37eb7b-297b-4aba-b383-73905ad16d62/)

But now another question: 
How to get the generated key from DB when INSERT is used? I see that when the INSERT command executed, my table (in memory) still contains 0, instead of key generated by DB.

Ofcourse I can use fill() method to get the updated value, but it looks very unoptimal.

Comment: Take a look at this answer to see if it solves your problem. Basically, you may need to tweak properties of the said column (the auto increment field) in your dataset designer (TableAdapter). http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/5b37eb7b-297b-4aba-b383-73905ad16d62/

Comment: Thanks for the link! But now I've got another question: how to get the generated key from DB? I see that when the INSERT command is executed, my table (in memory) still contains 0, instead of key generated by DB.

Comment: @llya I'm sorry I don't use TableAdapter so I can't really give you much guidance. If the INSERT sql generated returns the newly created identity (using either @@IDENTITY or SCOPE_IDENITY() (you should see it in the SQL statement generated) then it probably returns teh identity. Or there must be away (in the designer) to configure this. Maybe this question and answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704394/getting-identity-from-tableadapter